# Trying to make a multiple choice question

Tags: c++, duplicates

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  /**
  4 variants
  3 correct
  a b c d
  d is incorrecy
  if an answer is reapeted, it needs to say
      "Answer *a/b/c/d* has been already introduced"
  **/
  cout << "Which ones are correct?: a) b) c) d) \n";
  // for the sake of the example, only A B and C are correct
  string answer;
  int numberOfCorrectAnswers = 0;
  bool correct = true;

  while (true) {
    cin >> answer;
    if (answer == "a" || answer == "b" || answer == "c")
      numberOfCorrectAnswers++;

    else if (answer == "d")
      correct = false;

    if (answer == "Done")
      break;

    if (answer != "a" && answer != "b" && answer != "c" && answer != "d") {
      cout << "Input available answer!\n";
    }
  }

  if (correct == true && numberOfCorrectAnswers == 3)
    cout << numberOfCorrectAnswers;
  else
    cout << "Incorrect answers!";
  return 0;
}
```

I am trying to make a multiple choice question, yet I can't figure out how to make it so when I input an answer twice, it doesn't take it as correct and instead asks for a second input.

Example: `a a b Done (incorrect)`

Comment: As you iterate (using the `while` loop) you must keep track of which options have already been chosen. One boolean (`correct`) is not enough.

Comment: @Beta yeah i thought of that, only that i dont know how to implement it

Comment: There are several ways. You know how to use `correct`, so you could use `bool seen_a=false;` and the same for `b` and `c`.

Comment: ooooooh that makes sense thanks, might as well put it as an answer so i can give you points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a situation where you've either seen the option before or not seen it, it lends well to a binary flag like bool for the options. But since there are multiple options, it wouldn't be very maintainable to have flags for each variable. Imagine if your options go up to 5 or 6. You wouldn't want to be maintaining 6 different variables to keep track of whether you've already seen that option.

This use case again lends itself to arrays/vectors of bools. You could even use a [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) to keep track of the variables because finally you just want a 0 to represent not seen and 1 to indicate seen.

So, you could use something like this:

```
std::bitset<NUM_OPTIONS> optionFlags; //NUM_OPTIONS = 4 (a, b, c, d) for your example
```

To set the flag, based on the answer, you could do something like

```
size_t idx = answer[0] - 'a';
optionFlags.set(idx); //Set the bit for this option to test later
```

and then later on, while checking if the answer has already been seen, you could do

```
size_t idx = answer[0] - 'a';
if(optionFlags.test(idx)) { //Check if bit for the option is already set
   //Tell user that this option has already been entered earlier
}
```

There are multiple ways to achieve this using other data structures but usually, it would be somewhat similar, on these lines.

Comment: this is way too  much unknown syntax and theory for me, if you could link some sources from where i might be able to learn from?

Comment: @MickeyMoise [This](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/o-1-bit-flags-and-bit-manipulation-via-stdbitset/) is one resource I found. This is just one of the ways. If `std::bitset` seems something new, you could start with a simple array of booleans? But my purpose for writing this was to just illustrate the general idea that you would need a set of variables to keep track of each option and then check against that. How you implement this idea using any data structure is your choice.